# Incomplete implementation (xcode mistake?)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

//  9.1.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Complex : NSObject 
{

    double real;
    double imaginary;

}

@property double real, imaginary;
-(void) print;
-(void) setReal: (double) andImaginary: (double) b;
-(Complex *) add: (Complex *) f;

@end
```

---

```
#import "9.1.h"


@implementation Complex

@synthesize real, imaginary;

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@ "%g + %gi ", real, imaginary);
}

-(void) setReal: (double) a andImaginary: (double) b
{
    real = a;
    imaginary = b;
}

-(Complex *) add: (Complex *) f
{
    Complex *result = [[Complex alloc] init];

    [result setReal: real + [f real] andImaginary: imaginary + [f imaginary]];

    return result;

}
@end
```

On the final `@end` line, Xcode is telling me the implementation is incomplete. The code still works as expected, but I'm new at this and am worried I've missed something. It is complete as far as I can tell. Sometimes I feel like Xcode hangs on to past errors, but maybe I'm just losing my mind!

Thanks!
-Andrew

Comment: Could it be because the real parameter doesn't have a name in your interface `-(void) setReal: (double) andImaginary: (double) b;`

Comment: Kenny answered the question already, but I just wanted to point out that it's convention to return an autoreleased object from a method like your -add:

Comment: One further comment, with Value types like this it is good practise to make them immutable, i.e. set the real and imaginary components in the constructor and don't provide any means to change them. Do you have a specific need to modify instances of Complex once created?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `9.1.h`, you have missed an 'a'.

```
-(void) setReal: (double) andImaginary: (double) b;
//                       ^ here
```

---

The code is still valid, because in Objective-C a selector's part can have no name, e.g.

```
-(id)initWithControlPoints:(float)c1x :(float)c1y :(float)c2x :(float)c2y
//                                    ^           ^           ^
```

these methods are called as

```
return [self initWithControlPoints:0.0f :0.0f :1.0f :1.0f];
//                                      ^     ^     ^
```

and the selector name is naturally `@selector(initWithControlPoints::::)`.

Therefore, the compiler will interpret your declaration as

```
-(void)setReal:(double)andImaginary
              :(double)b;
```

since you have not provided the implementation of this `-setReal::` method, gcc will warn you about

```
warning: incomplete implementation of class ‘Complex’
warning: method definition for ‘-setReal::’ not found
```

---

BTW, if you just want a complex value but doesn't need it to be an Objective-C class, there is [C99 complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex.h), e.g.

```
#include <complex.h>

...

double complex z = 5 + 6I;
double complex w = -4 + 2I;
z = z + w;
printf("%g + %gi\n", creal(z), cimag(z));
```